# What kind of different information can be had/ascertained in the logs with the various entries in logs

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, debian, log

I am running Debian Jessie and running TBB 3.6.5. This can be known by running `torbrowser-launcher` . I am using the torbrowser-launcher as packaged in Debian.

On studying the manual, I came to know that the log by default only shows warnings. Something like :-

```
Sep 19 01:24:55.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 80%: Connecting to the Tor network. (Network is unreachable; NOROUTE; count 519; recommendation warn)
```

The manual page tells that you could do some more things :-

> By default, Tor starts out logging messages at level "notice" and
>   higher to the console. It stops doing so after it parses its
>   configuration, if the configuration tells it to log anywhere else. You
>   can override this behavior with the --hush option, which tells Tor to
>   only send warnings and errors to the console, or with the --quiet
>   option, which tells Tor not to log to the console at all.
>
> Other options can be specified on the command-line in the format
>   "--option value", in the format "option value", or in a configuration
>   file. For instance, you can tell Tor to start listening for SOCKS
>   connections on port 9999 by passing --SOCKSPort 9999 or SOCKSPort 9999
>   to it on the command line, or by putting "SOCKSPort 9999" in the
>   configuration file. You will need to quote options with spaces in
>   them: if you want Tor to log all debugging messages to debug.log, you
>   will probably need to say --Log debug file debug.log.

Now the first thing seems to be that Tor is not documented on the CLI itself. It took me quite sometime to understand where the Tor browser is in my system and aliased it to make it more accessible.

```
$ alias tor
alias tor='/home/shirish/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser'
```

I also tried to see if there were any --help triggers but found it wanting :-

```
$ ./start-tor-browser --help
usage: ./start-tor-browser [--debug]
```

So can somebody share with me some examples of the different types of entries
in the log, for example if I use WARN/DEBUG/INFO/TRACE. I also don't know if all the different characteristics are allowed or only one of them.

Another query, do I need to have multiple logs or a single log can have all the different characteristics I want to know and understand.

Looking forward to knowing more. As of right now, my objective is to first get the logs happening which is not happening, see the follow-up question, only then can I come back to this.

Follow-up question :- [Follow-up question: Why my log is not showing tor_notices.log and tor_traces.log?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4160/follow-up-question-why-my-log-is-not-showing-tor-notices-log-and-tor-traces-log)

Comment: If you wish to tell someone something please use the comments and "add" them with "@Cammy_the_block". Also if my answer was useful/solved your question please vote and or mark as answered to help future guests.

Comment: I think you're mixing up Tor, Tor Browser and the Launcher. Have a look at the following Q&A. This might help: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4192/88

Comment: At the moment it is quite unclear what your question really is. Can you edit it to make clear what you really want to know? For the moment I'll close it.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. I just had a look in the source code and Tor has more than 400 [`LOG` entries](https://gitweb.torproject.org//tor.git?a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=LOG) there. So it might be better if you explain what entries you're looking for or maybe explain the background of your question.

Comment: I am looking for log entries to know how many times my IP Address changes during a tor session.

Answer (score 4):

The different levels are as follows ([Tor Docs](https://stem.torproject.org/api/util/log.html))

> ERROR     critical issue occurred, the user needs to be notified
>
> **WARN     non-critical issue occurred that the user should be aware of**
>
> **NOTICE   information that is helpful to the user**
>
> INFO   high level library activity
>
> DEBUG  low level library activity
>
> TRACE  request/reply logging

Warn means that an issue occurred such as not being able to make a circuit. A notice is just information that user might find useful such as bootstrapping being complete.

These are by no means the only warnings or notices.

Comment: What about INFO then ? Does it tell anything about the circtuits tor makes ?

Comment: @shirish I believe so. As I said the warnings and notices I said are not the only ones.