# What is the difference between Tor, Tor Browser and torbrowser-launcher?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I often see those three different kind of software and want to know how/if they differ. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tor, sometimes called little-t-tor, is the core of the Tor Project's software. It acts as a SOCKS proxy and anonymizes your connection. You can set up Tor in your `torrc`. This file is either in the directory `/etc/tor` when Tor is installed as a system-wide daemon or it is in your local home directory when you use the Tor Browser.

Tor Browser is a browser (like Firefox) which comes with Tor and some other software. This software enables you to safely access the web in a secure way. You can change settings by pressing the green onion inside Tor Browser or by entering `about:config` into the URL bar.

The [torbrowser-launcher](https://micahflee.com/torbrowser-launcher/) is a software which starts your Tor Browser. It checks if a new version is available, downloads if there is any and starts the Tor Browser. It only has one parameter (`--settings`) which opens a settings dialogue.